# Passing data from listView to another Activity EditText

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout

I am displaying data in listView and on long Press on listView i want to update its data and pass its data to another Update activity Edit texts.

my code for displaying:

```
public class Retreivedata extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference ref;
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Member member;
 Button btnDlt;
 Boolean a=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retreivedata);
    member = new Member();
   listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnDlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDlt);
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   ref = database.getReference("Member");
   list = new ArrayList<>();
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for(DataSnapshot dts: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                     {
                         member = dts.getValue(Member.class);
                         list.add("Name :"+member.getName().toString()+" Age 
            :"+member.getAge().toString()+" Phone :"+member.getPhone().toString()+"\n"+"------------- 
      -----------");
           }
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });

      btnDlt.setEnabled(false);
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Boolean a=true;
          String item = adapter.getItem(position);
          Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this,"Do u want to delete this 
        record!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if (a==true)
          {
              btnDlt.setEnabled(true);

          }else{
              btnDlt.setEnabled(false);
          }
      }
          });

  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String item = adapter.getItem(position).toString();
          Intent intent = new Intent(Retreivedata.this, Update.class);
          intent.putExtra("tem",item);
          startActivity(intent);
          return false;
      }
  });

    btnDlt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                ref.child(member.getMemberId()).removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this, "Record deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter.remove(val);
                adapter.clear();
            }
    });

}
}
```

I want to recive Name,age,phone,height data in every EditText in another activity .

My code for Receiving data:

```
public class Update extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText EditTxtName,EditTxtAge,txtPhone,txtHeight;
Button btnUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    EditTxtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxtName);
    EditTxtAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxtAge);
    txtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
    btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    String TempHolder = getIntent().getStringExtra("tem");

    EditTxtName.setText(TempHolder);
}
}
```

I receive all data in EditTxtName but i want to set that data in its Edittexts.

Please suggest me how to do so..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` your `member class` :

**First way `Serializable` like this :**

```
public class Member implements Serializable{
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public void setId(int id) {
           this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId() {
           return id;
        }
        public String getName() {
           return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }
}
```

Then you can pass this object like this :

```
 Member member=adapter.getItem(position);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Update.class);
 intent.putExtra("tem", member);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And you can get data like this :

```
Member member= (Member) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tem");
```

THen you can set per data in its EditText like this :

```
EditTxtName.setName(member.name);
```

**Second way `Parcelable` like this :**

```
public class ObjectA implements Parcelable
{
    private String name = null;
    private int id = 0;


    public ObjectA()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {

        this.name = in.readString();
        this.id = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

Then pass your data like this :

```
            Member member=adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Update.class);
            intent.putExtra("tem", member);
            startActivity(i);
```

And get it like this :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Member member = bundle.getParcelable("tem");
```

Then set it to editText like this :

```
EditTxtName.setName(member.name);
```

Comment: I am getting error Incompatible types here    Member member=adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: I think I am getting error because i am using ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; beacuase i am passing String not Member class

Comment: Yes definitely , you should use object in your adapter!!
Its meaningless showing String in an adapter.

Comment: now i am getting error here     :                          list.add("Name :"+member.getName().toString()+" Age :"+member.getAge().toString()+" Phone :"+member.getPhone().toString()+"\n"+"------------------------"); the error is add in Arraylist cant be applied because i have changed ArrayList<String> list to ArrayList<Member> list

Comment: When you change your String type to Member , you should change your approach in your adapter , i should check whole your codes.
You should have something like this : `list.add(member)`

Comment: i did this but when displaying records it is not displaying data it is displaying Package name com.example.... and after long pressing on it,it opens another activity and passes data......but now how to display records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213316/discussion-between-ravish-and-milad-salimi).